# How do I implement AAD login not in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I am learning Azure, AAD, WS-Federation, claims, etc. and wanted to write a simple web server in C# (without using ASP.NET) that requires user authentication using AAD, just to learn how things work. But I have been unable to find even a single example of how this is done!

I tried reading about WIF but everything goes back to having an ASP.NET server.

Answer (score 1):

WAAD Authentication using Native Clients - [Tutorial by Vittorio Bertocchi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn463788.aspx)

Comment: I'm implementing a Web Server, not a native client.

Comment: Yes, but you can get the core part of how authentication is being handled from that tutorial. Also you cannot get Username and password directly from user and authenticate him. WAAD's Graph API doesn't support that. So you can use WAAD Authentication library as shown in the tutorial I linked.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are talking about "Secure ASP.NET Web API with Windows Azure AD and Microsoft OWIN Components"? this is the linked tutorial.

Comment: Yes I am sure I am talking about that. But my main focus is the code which used ADAL and performs authentication. As I already mentioned there is no Graph API support for WAAD which you can use to authenticate users by their username and password. AFAIK, you need to use ADAL or ACS to perform auth against WAAD. You can find ACS examples any where (as you mentioned in your question), so I shared ADAL sample with you.